# Show default browser dialog to prevent user from going back

Tags: reactjs, react-router, back-button, onbeforeunload

I know many questions about this have already been asked but I'm struggling finding what I need. I am using react-router 5.1.2 to manage navigation in my web-app. I want to alert the user before he leaves the page. [Attach beforeUnload listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) does not work when users press the browser's back button. I understand I can use `history.block()` or `<Prompt>`, but the alert does not behaves like the default one shown when beforeUnload is fired, e.g. I can press back button twice then press "cancel" and have inconsistencies between the route and the actual rendered component. The question is: how can I alert the user pressing back button obtaining a confirmation dialog that behaves as the default one (preventing further actions other than those proposed by the alert)?

This is the custom hook I've used so far:

```js
const alertUser = (e: BeforeUnloadEvent | PopStateEvent) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = '';
};
export const useAlertBeforeLeaving = (showAlert = true) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const unblock = useRef<UnregisterCallback | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showAlert) {
      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', alertUser);
      unblock.current = history.block('Leave the page?');
    }
    return () => {
      if (showAlert && unblock.current) {
        window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', alertUser);
        unblock.current();
      }
    };
  }, [history, showAlert]);
};
```